# Is there a reason why so many Latin America countries enforce compulsory voting?

Tags: voting, international, latin-america

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_voting

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_voting#/media/File:Compulsory_voting.svg

It seems like most Latin America country enforce compulsory voting, and it seems strange because throughout the world there aren't  many countries that enforce it. Is there a reason why so many Latin America countries enforce compulsory voting?

Comment: Maybe just tradition, same reason North American countries don't

Comment: @user253751 All Latin American countries that have it introduced compulsory voting only in the 20th century (and with the exception of Argentina only after WWI), long after independence.

Comment: I suspect there's some copycat effect there. But it would be interesting to hear why it is/was perceived as a success story (enough to copy) in this particular region.

Comment: There is an entire dissertation on this: https://ir.vanderbilt.edu/bitstream/handle/1803/14666/Maldonado.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: It seems to go back to Vargas, and was introduced in many different countries in the 1930s This suggests it was something to do with the response to the great depression, and to rising nationalism, or to a general trend for constitutions to be re-written at that time in more nationalist/populist terms, with the notion of the "citizen's duty" rather than "citizen's rights" to vote.